# Set node environment variable to dynamic value in npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app, npm-scripts

I would like to set an environment variable dynamically in an npm script.

I'm using `cross-env` as I'm developing on Windows and the server is Unix-based. I want to initialize an environment variable with the current date (`new Date()`) so I can access and render it in my `create-react-app`:

This works (hard-coded string):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env-shell REACT_APP_BUILD_DATE=\"currentDate\" react-scripts-ts start",
}
```

Obviously, `currentDate` shouldn't be a string but the result of following expression: `new Date()`.

How can I achieve that? In other words: How can evaluate some regular JavaScript and use its result an npm script? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Why not simply use `new Date()` inside your CRA app? What's the reason to pass it as an environment variable?

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović, the goal is to save the build date, not just get a date at the time that the app was opened.

Answer (score 8):

I am using simple node script for passing environment variables into called script. It uses child_process.execSync.

```
// File name: ./build.js
/* eslint-env node */
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const env = Object.create(process.env);

env.REACT_APP_BUILD_DATE= Date.now();

console.log('Used env variables: ' + JSON.stringify(env));
console.log('Run command: react-scripts start');
execSync('react-scripts-ts start', { env: env, stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Update start command in package.json scripts. like this:

```
"scripts": {"start": "node ./build.js"}
```

Comment: This is the only way to make it work on poor windows systems

I added

`env['REACT_APP_GIT_SHA'] = execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD', { encoding: 'utf-8' }).trim()`

and modified the last line to make it work


`execSync('npx react-scripts start', { env: env, stdio: 'inherit' });`

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I'm now using following approach: Write current date to a custom property in package.json and read that value in the app by importing `package.json`

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
  "build": "node ./update-packagejson.js && react-scripts-ts build"
}
```

**update-packagejson.js**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const filePath = "./package.json";

const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString());
packageJson.ngrvd.buildDate = new Date().toUTCString();

fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(packageJson, null, 2));
```

**Component**

```
import { ngrvd, version } from "../../package.json";

// ... 

private static getAppInfo(): string {
  const buildDate = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? new Date() : ngrvd.buildDate;
  return "Version " + version + "  - Built " + moment(buildDate).fromNow();
}
```

This works on any environment, is simple and understandable and could be extended to also contain other information. When in dev mode I don't write to `package.json` to prevent having local changes everytime.

Comment: Went there, did that... if you resort on writing into a file beforehand, try writing into an `.env` file and use the library https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv to populate environment variables with it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to mention the dotenv solution

Answer (score 1):

For example you want to put build time to your reactjs app. Edit `package.json` like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME=$(date +%s) react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME=$(date +%s) react-app-rewired build"
}
```

You can use `REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME`  variable in `public/index.html` file. For example:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico?%REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME%" />
```

You must wrap env variable with `%` characters. And there is another rule: you must add `REACT_APP_` to your env variable. You can not add other env variables to react app.

**How can you add all `.env` variables to reactjs app?**

You can use `env-cmd` package for this.

`yarn add env-cmd`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME=$(date +%s) ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME=$(date +%s) ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd react-app-rewired build"
}
```

Example `.env` content:

```
REACT_APP_NAME="My React App"
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=https://127.0.0.1:8080/api
REACT_APP_SOCKETIO_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:3333
```

After that you can add these variables to your `public/index.html` file like that:

```
<script>
  window.env.REACT_APP_NAME = "%REACT_APP_NAME%";
  window.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT = "%REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT%";
  window.env.REACT_APP_SOCKETIO_ENDPOINT = "%REACT_APP_SOCKETIO_ENDPOINT%";
</script>
```

In reactjs side you can use these variables like that:

```
alert(window.env.REACT_APP_SOCKETIO_ENDPOINT);
```

That's all.

Edit: Normally there is no this property: `window.env` but we set this now for easy to use. You can assign your env variables to anywhere in `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you'd be better off using shell command instead of JavaScript, so it should be something like the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env-shell REACT_APP_BUILD_DATE=$(date '+%F %H:%M:%S') react-scripts-ts start",
}
```

Comment: Using this approach I get following error: `react-scripts-ts was unexpected at this time.`. If I add the quotes again, then the value of the variable is `$(date +%F %H:%M:%S)`. Can this be related to Windows?

Comment: Oh man, Windows. Sorry, my bad, missed this fact. Then yeah, you should probably go with the script approach @remix23 is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a custom javascript script doing it for you:

**execute.js**

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// because first arg will actually be something like "./execute.js"
// this is the "regular javascript" you want to evaluate
var arg1 = process.argv[1];
// so lets eval it
var res = eval(arg1);
// this is the remaining args, that is the command you want to run (and its args)
var command = process.argv[2];
var commandArgs = process.argv.slice(3);
// if arg1 evaluation resulted in a value, append this value to the list of args
if (res) {
    commandArgs.push(res);
}
// execute the command
var prc = spawn(command, commandArgs);
```

and your script definition will become:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env-shell ./execute.js \"process.env.REACT_APP_BUILD_DATE = new Date();\" react-scripts-ts start",
}
```

Or something similar.

This is untested but should get you started on a solution for "**evaluate some regular JavaScript and use its result an npm script**"

But if you only want to set a date in a env variable, the solution from @bredikhin is better.

***ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION TO DEAL WITH ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES***

If you can afford to write into an `.env`file at the root of your project (by hand or programatically), you can then use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to populate environment variables with it (from [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) documentation):

```
// Usage
// As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

require('dotenv').config()
/* Create a .env file in the root directory of your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of NAME=VALUE. For example:

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
That's it.

process.env now has the keys and values you defined in your .env file.
*/
const db = require('db');
db.connect({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it didn't quite work out. I'm now writing the current date to package.json using a js-script and then reading it from there. See my answer below for more details.